# tdplotsetrotatedcoord ' arguments

Tags: tikz-3dplot, coordinates

This involves making a pyramid (tetrahedral, SABCD) in a red reference frame of origin (A) = (0,0) and dimension 2 cm then tracing a green triangle on the face ((S), (B), (C))
for this it would undoubtedly be necessary to momentarily determine a reference point (blue) of origin (B), of abscissa coincident with the half-line [BC), therefore parallel to the main abscissa axis and of ordinate coincident with the half-right [BS).

The green triangle must be drawn using the path `(start) -- ++(60:2) -- ++(-60:2) -- cycle`. I am unable to finalize the lines of code for calculating the arguments of `\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\alpha}{\beta}{\gamma}`. The code below compiles, only the calculation needs to be corrected. Note: the leading coefficient of BC (therefore of the abscissa in the blue marker) is the same as that of the line AD in the original red marker (A). We can introduce other focus lines on the model `\node at (0,0, -5) {alpha: \alpha, beta: \beta gamma; \gamma}`

```
\input{preambule-utf8.ltx}
 


\begin{document}
 
    
    
    \newcommand{\DefinePoints}[1]{%
        \foreach \x/\y/\z/\name in {#1} {
            \coordinate (\name) at (\x, \y, \z);
        }
    }
    

        
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{120}  % Si absent, « tdplot_main_coords » sera inconnu 
                
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,
    line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,scale=2]
    
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{120} 

\draw[line width=1pt, red] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[below right]{$X$};
\draw[line width=1pt, red] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0) node[below right]{$Y$};
\draw[line width=1pt, red] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2.5) node[below right]{$Z$};


\def\cote{2}
\DefinePoints{
    0/                0/                      0/A, 
    \cote/                0/                      0/B,
    \cote/         \cote/                      0/C,
    0/          \cote/                     0/D,
    0.5*\cote/  0.5*\cote/         \cote     /S,
    0/                0/          \cote     /Z%
}       

\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
\foreach \point in {A, B, C, D} {
    \draw  (S)  -- (\point);
}

\draw  (A) -- (S) -- (B);
\draw   (B) -- (S) -- (C);

% Calcul des angles pour le changemnt de repère momentané 

    \tdplotsetrotatedcoordsorigin{(A)}
    

% Calcul des vecteurs BC, BS et AD
\coordinate (BC) at ($(C)-(B)$);
\coordinate (BS) at ($(S)-(B)$);
\coordinate (AD) at ($(D)-(A)$);

% Calcul des vecteurs BC, BS et AD
\coordinate (BC) at ($(C)-(B)$);
\coordinate (BS) at ($(S)-(B)$);
\coordinate (AD) at ($(D)-(A)$);



% Calcul de l'angle α entre BC et l'axe x
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints
{\pgfpoint{1cm}{0cm}}
{\pgfpointanchor{BC}{center}}
\let\alpha\pgfmathresult

% Calcul de l'angle β entre BS et l'axe y
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints
{\pgfpoint{0cm}{1cm}}
{\pgfpointanchor{BS}{center}}
\let\beta\pgfmathresult

% Calcul de l'angle γ entre AD et l'axe z
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints
{\pgfpoint{1cm}{0cm}}
{\pgfpointanchor{AD}{center}}
\let\gamma\pgfmathresult

% Utiliser ces angles pour définir le repère bleu
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\alpha}{\beta}{\gamma}

    \tdplotsetrotatedcoordsorigin{(B)}

\node at (0,0, -5)  {alpha : \alpha, beta : \beta gamma ; \gamma} ; 

\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
    
    % Draw blue axes
    \draw[blue, thick,->](0,0)--(3,0,0)node[below right]{$X'$};
    \draw[blue, thick,->](0,0)--(0,3,0)node[below left]{$Y'$};
    \draw[blue, thick,->](0,0)--(0,0,3)node[above]{$Z'$};    
    
  \draw[-, green, line width=2pt] (B) -- ++(60:2) -- ++(-60:2) ; %   -- cycle ;
    
\end{scope}




\foreach \n/\pos  in {S/above, A/{above left}, B/{above left}, C/below, D/{above right}, Z/right}{
    \tkzDrawPoint (\n)
    \tkzLabelPoints[\pos](\n)           
} 
\node at (0,0, -5)  {alpha : \alpha, beta : \beta gamma ; \gamma} ; 
    
\end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

Thank you for helping me let go of my obsessive compulsive disorder resulting from my inability to solve this problem 80)

[image: Ce que j'espère][image: Objectif plus lointain]

---

I tried to be more explicit in the comment of my code taking into account my reading of "tikz-3dplot_documentation.pdf" something must be escaping me since the result is:

[image]

with the following code.

```
    \newcommand{\DefinePoints}[1]{%
        \foreach \x/\y/\z/\name in {#1} {
            \coordinate (\name) at (\x, \y, \z);
        }
    }
    
    
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{120}%
 

    \begin{tikzpicture} [ 
             tdplot_main_coords,        
             cube/.style={very thick,black},
              grid/.style={very thin,gray},
                           axis/.style={->,blue,thick},
           rotated axis/.style={->,purple,thick},
           line cap=round,
           line join=round,
           >=triangle 45,
           scale=3]
  
  \draw[axis, tdplot_main_coords, red] (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0) node[anchor=south]{$x$};
 \draw[axis,  tdplot_main_coords, red] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
  \draw[axis, tdplot_main_coords, red] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3) node[anchor=west]{$z$};
  
  
  \def\cote{2}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\hauteur}{sqrt(3) } 
   
  \DefinePoints{
    0/                0/                      0/A, 
    \cote/                0/                      0/B,
    \cote/         \cote/                      0/C,
    0/          \cote/                     0/D,
    0.5*\cote/  0.5*\cote/    \hauteur  /S,
    0/                0/          \cote     /Z%
  }       
  
  \draw[ ] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
  \foreach \point in {A, B, C, D} {
    \draw  (S)  -- (\point);
  }
  
  \draw[ ]  (A) -- (S) -- (B);
  \draw[ ]   (B) -- (S) -- (C);
 
% -------------------------------------------- 
% Calculate the rotation angles
% α (alpha) : Rotation z of α degrees to align the z' axis with the global Z axis
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints
{\pgfpointanchor{B}{center}}
{\pgfpointanchor{Z}{center}}
\let\alpha\pgfmathresult

% β (beta) : Rotation y of β degrees with respect to the system resulting from the first rotation
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints
{\pgfpointanchor{B}{center}}
{\pgfpointanchor{D}{center}} % Use the point corresponding to the Y axis in the system resulting from the first rotation
\let\beta\pgfmathresult

% γ (gamma) : Rotation z of γ degrees with respect to the system resulting from the first two rotations
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints
{\pgfpointanchor{B}{center}}
{\pgfpointanchor{B}{center}} % Use the point corresponding to the X axis in the system resulting from the first two rotations
\let\gamma\pgfmathresult

\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{60}{90}{0}

\tdplotsetrotatedcoordsorigin{(B)}

% ---------------------------------------------------
 

    \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
 
 
    % draw the rotated coordinate frame axes
    \draw[rotated axis, blue, line width=1pt] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[anchor=west]{$x'$};
    \draw[rotated axis, blue, line width=1pt]  (0,0,0) -- (0,4,0) node[anchor=south west]{$y'$};
    \draw[rotated axis, blue, line width=1pt]  (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3) node[anchor=west]{$z'$};
    
    
    \draw (0,0,0) -- (1.5*\cote,0,0) -- (1.5*\cote, 1.5*\cote, 0) -- (0,1.5*\cote,0) -- cycle ; 
 
 % Tracer le triangle vert avec un chemin relatif dans le plan (SBC)    
  
  \draw[-, green, line width=2pt] (B) -- ++(60:2) -- ++(-60:2) ; %   -- cycle ;
 
    
 \end{scope} 
  
    \node at (1,-1, -2)  {alpha : \alpha } ; 
   \node at (1,-1, -2.5)  {beta  : \beta} ; 
  \node at (1,-1, -3)  {gamma : \gamma} ; 
  
                
        \foreach \n/\pos  in {S/above, A/{above left}, B/{above left}, C/below, D/{above right}, Z/right}{
            \tkzDrawPoint (\n)
            \tkzLabelPoints[\pos](\n)           
        } 
 

    \end{tikzpicture}
```

I'm losing sleep!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). The document class is missing and others don't have `preambule-utf8.ltx`.

Answer (score 1):

I found sleep again[image]

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
 
 \usepackage{tkz-base}
 \usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
 %
 % Jj Dhénin: 2023/10/11
 
 % Uncomment if necessary
 % \newcommand{\MainAxes}{}  % main_coords,
 % \newcommand{\RotatedAxes}{}  % rotated axis,
 % \newcommand{\FacilitateFocus}{}
 
 \tikzset{
    axis/.style={->, blue, thick},
    rotated axis/.style={->, purple, thick},
    base/.style={gray!60},
    line cap=round,
    line join=round,
    >=triangle 45,
    base/.style={gray!50}
 }
 
 \begin{document}
    
    % Following the tkz-euclide model, "\definePoints"
    \newcommand{\DefinePoints}[1]{%
        \foreach \x/\y/\z/\name in {#1} {
            \coordinate (\name) at (\x, \y, \z);
        }
    }
    
    % The small base triangle
    % #1: Initial position, e.g., (X)
    % #2: Length of the triangle's side
    % #3: Color and other style arguments
    \newcommand\faisUn[3] {\fill[#3] #1  -- ++(-60:#2)  -- ++(-#2,0) -- cycle;
    }
    
    % Three "solid" triangles around an empty triangle
    % #1: Initial position, e.g., (X)
    % #2: Length of the triangle's side
    % #3: Color and other style arguments
    \newcommand{\faisTrois}[3]{
        \coordinate  (X) at (#1) ;
        \coordinate  (tmpA) at (X) ;
        \def\coteA{#2}
        \faisUn{(X)} {\coteA}{#3}
        \coordinate (X) at ([shift={(-120:\coteA)}]X);
        \faisUn{(X)} {\coteA} {#3}
        \coordinate (X) at ([shift={(\coteA,0)}]X);
        \faisUn{(X)} {\coteA} {#3}
        \coordinate  (X) at (tmpA) ;
    }
    
    % Three times three "solid" triangles around an empty triangle
    % #1: Initial position, e.g., (X)
    % #2: Length of the triangle's side
    % #3: Color and other style arguments
    \newcommand{\faisNeuf}[3]{
        \coordinate  (X) at (#1) ;
        \coordinate  (tmpB) at (X) ;
        \def\coteB{#2}
        
        \faisTrois{X}{\coteB}{#3}
        
        \coordinate (X) at ([shift={(-120:2*\coteB)}]X);
        
        \faisTrois{X}{\coteB}{#3}
        \coordinate (X) at ([shift={(2*\coteB,0)}]X);
        
        \faisTrois{X}{\coteB}{#3}
        
        \coordinate  (X) at (tmpB) ;
    }
    
    % 3 x three times 3 "solid" triangles around an empty triangle
    % #1: Initial position, e.g., (X)
    % #2: Length of the triangle's side
    % #3: Color and other style arguments
    \newcommand{\faisTroisNeuf}[3]{
        \coordinate  (X) at (#1) ;
        \coordinate  (tmpC) at (X) ;
        \def\coteC{#2}
        
        \faisNeuf{X}{\coteC}{#3}
        
        \coordinate (X) at ([shift={(-120:4*\coteB)}]X);
        \faisNeuf{X}{\coteC}{#3}
        
        \coordinate (X) at ([shift={(4*\coteB,0)}]X);
        \faisNeuf{X}{\coteC}{#3}
    }
    
    % ------------
    % Create a face based on
    % #1: Orientation of the abscissas according to the face
    % #2: Bottom-left vertex of the face (A or B or C or D)
    % #3: Color and other style of the face
    % #4: Step (level of division)
    \newcommand\faireFace[4]{
        
        \def\alpha{#1}
        %   \beta has been calculated once and for all during initialization
        \def\gamma{90}
        
        % Origin at the bottom right of the triangle
        \tdplotsetrotatedcoordsorigin{#2}
        
        \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\alpha}{\beta}{\gamma}
        
        \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
            \ifdefined\RotatedAxes
            \draw[rotated axis, blue, line width=1pt] (0,0,0) -- (5,0,0) node[anchor=west]{$x'$};
            \draw[rotated axis, blue, line width=1pt]  (0,0,0) -- (0,4,0) node[anchor=south west]{$y'$};
            \draw[rotated axis, blue, line width=1pt]  (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3) node[anchor=west]{$z'$};
            \fi
            
            % Use the top of the triangle to position it, regardless of its size
            \coordinate  (X) at (S) ;
            
            \ifnum #4=4
            \def\cote{4}    % Length of the edge
            \def\coteDeco{0.25} % Length of the side of the small triangle
            \faisTroisNeuf{X} {\coteDeco}{#3}
            
            \coordinate (X) at ([shift={(-0.25*\cote,0)}]X);
            \coordinate (X) at ([shift={(-120:0.25*\cote)}]X);
            
            \faisTroisNeuf{X} {\coteDeco}{#3}
            
            \coordinate (X) at ([shift={(0.25*\cote,0)}]X);
            \coordinate (X) at ([shift={(60:0.25*\cote)}]X);
            \faisTroisNeuf{X} {\coteDeco}{#3}
            \fi
            \ifnum #4=3
            \def\cote{4}    % Length of the edge
            \def\coteDeco{0.5} % Length of the side of the small triangle
            
            \faisNeuf{X}{\coteDeco}{#3}
            
            \coordinate (X) at ([shift={(-120:0.5*\cote)}]X);
            \faisNeuf{X}{\coteDeco}{#3}
            
            \coordinate (X) at ([shift={(0.5*\cote,0)}]X);
            \faisNeuf{X}{\coteDeco}{#3}
            
            \fi
            
            \ifnum #4=2
            \def\cote{4}    % Length of the edge
            \def\coteDeco{1} % Length of the side of the small triangle
            
            \faisTrois{X}{\coteDeco}{#3}
            
            \coordinate (X) at ([shift={(-120:0.5*\cote)}]X);
            \faisTrois{X}{\coteDeco}{#3}
            
            \coordinate (X) at ([shift={(0.5*\cote,0)}]X);
            \faisTrois{X}{\coteDeco}{#3}
            
            \fi
            
            \ifnum #4=1
            
            \def\cote{4}    % Length of the edge
            \def\coteDeco{2} % Length of the side of the small triangle
            
            \faisUn{(X)} {\coteDeco} {#3}
            
            \coordinate (X) at ([shift={(-120:0.5*\cote)}]X);
            \faisUn{(X)} {\coteDeco} {#3}
            
            \coordinate (X) at ([shift={(0.5*\cote,0)}]X);
            \faisUn{(X)} {\coteDeco} {#3}
            
            \fi
            
            \ifnum #4=0
            
            \def\cote{4}    % Length of the edge
            \def\coteDeco{4} % Length of the side of the small triangle
            
            \faisUn{(X)} {\coteDeco} {#3}
            
            \fi
            
        \end{scope}
    } % End of command faireFace
    
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{120}%
    
    % We need five different pyramids
    % #1: Step number
    % #2: Measurement of the pyramid
    % #3: Measurement of the triangle's side (according to the step)
    \newcommand\faisLaPyramide[1]{
        \setbox1\hbox{
            \begin{tikzpicture} [
                tdplot_main_coords,
                scale=0.35       % Set the scale here!
                ]
                
                % Draw the main axes
                \ifdefined\MainAxes
                \draw[axis, tdplot_main_coords, red] (0,0,0) -- (5,0,0) node[anchor=south]{$x$};
                \draw[axis,  tdplot_main_coords, red] (0,0,0) -- (0,5,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
                \draw[axis, tdplot_main_coords, red] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3) node[anchor=west]{$z$};
                \fi
                
                % Initialization of characteristics
                \def\cote{4}    % Length of the edge
                
                \def\coteDeco{0.25} % Length of the side of the small triangle
                % Measurement of the height of the main face
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\SMbc} {sqrt( (\cote)^2   -    (0.5*\cote)^2 }
                % Measurement of the height of the pyramid
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\hauteur}   {sqrt( (\SMbc)^2   -    (0.5*\cote)^2 }
                
                % Angle of a face with the base
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\beta}{atan2(\hauteur, 0.5*\cote}
                % Vertices and useful points
                \DefinePoints{
                    0/                0/                      0/A,
                    \cote/                0/                      0/B,
                    \cote/         \cote/                      0/C,
                    0/          \cote/                     0/D,
                    0.5*\cote/  0.5*\cote/    \hauteur  /S,
                    \cote/  0.5*\cote/    0/Mbc
                }
                
                % Shaded base
                \fill [base] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
                
                \ifdefined\FacilitateFocus
                % Pyramid's contour
                \foreach \point in {A, B, C, D} {
                    \draw  (S)  -- (\point);
                }
                
                \draw[ ]  (A) -- (S) -- (B);
                \draw[ ]   (B) -- (S) -- (C);
                \fi
                
                % Face on the right (DSA)
                % Starting with a face hidden by the front
                \faireFace{180} {(D)} {red!40}  {#1}   % Perspective distorts and deceives
                
                % Front face on the right (DSA)
                \faireFace{270}  {(A)} {red!50} {#1}    % Perspective distorts and deceives
                
                % Front face on the left (BSC)
                \faireFace{0} {(B)}  {red!60} {#1}
                
                % Front face on the right (CSD)
                \faireFace{90}  {(C)} {red!70} {#1}
                
                \ifdefined\FacilitateFocus
                \foreach \n/\pos  in {S/above, A/{above left}, B/{above left}, C/below, D/{above right},   Mbc/below}{
                    \tkzDrawPoint (\n)
                    \tkzLabelPoints[\pos](\n)
                }
                \fi
                
            \end{tikzpicture}
        } % End of setbox1\hbox
    } % End of command\faisLaPyramide
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \faisLaPyramide{0}
        \node at (0,0) {\box1};
        
        \faisLaPyramide{1}
        \node at (2,0) {\box1};
        
        \faisLaPyramide{2}
        \node at (4,0) {\box1};
        
        \faisLaPyramide{3}
        \node at (6,0) {\box1};
        
        \faisLaPyramide{4}
        \node at (8,0) {\box1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
 \end{document}
```

Bien cordialement